# How to remove the ProgressBar from Facebook login sdk

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar, facebook-sdk-4.0

By implementing the Facebook Login with android I need to send the token tom my back-end server, so I was wondering if I could remove the Progress bar and create my own progress, dispose after getting the Facebook Token and sending to my server. It appears when I call :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(Login.this,Arrays.asList("email"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the Facebook login ProgressBar like this:

In `values/styles.xml` add the following style:

```
<style name="Translucent" parent="Translucent.Base"/>

<style name="InvisibleProgress">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>

<style name="Translucent.Base" parent="android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/InvisibleProgress</item>
</style>
```

In `values-v21/styles.xml` add the following style:

```
<style name="Translucent" parent="Translucent.Base">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then, in your `AndroidManifest.xml` override the theme of the `FacebookActivity`:

```
<manifest
  ...
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>

...

<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Translucent"
    tools:replace="android:theme"
/>
```

Now you will not see the Facebook progress bar and you can draw your own :)

Comment: Its not finding the "parent="Translucent.Base""

Comment: I forgot to add it to the `values/styles.xml`. It's there now + the `InvisibleProgress` style :)

Comment: It did worked, thanks! Just one more question, it blinks the android navigation controls, its normal ?

Comment: It's the transition effect of the FacebookActivity that causes this. Try removing the last 2 items from the `v-21` styles, the `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` and `android:statusBarColor`. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest  com.facebook.FacebookActivity

change theme like below

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"

instead of

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

Comment: I did, but still showing but now like the old design